# 24 hr countdown loop in angular js

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Hello am just knew to angular, how can you translate this code into angularjs. My goal is to have it count down 24hrs and restarts again

```
 setInterval(function time(){
  var d = new Date();
  var hours = 24 - d.getHours();
  var min = 60 - d.getMinutes();
  if((min + '').length == 1){
    min = '0' + min;
  }
  var sec = 60 - d.getSeconds();
  if((sec + '').length == 1){
        sec = '0' + sec;
  }
  jQuery('#the-final-countdown p').html(hours+':'+min+':'+sec)
}, 1000);
```

This is the html

```
<div id="the-final-countdown">
<p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Check [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) in the Angular docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap the funciton `setInterval` into `$interval` in your controller like this:

```
$interval(function time(){
  var d = new Date();
  var hours = 24 - d.getHours();
  var min = 60 - d.getMinutes();
  if((min + '').length == 1){
    min = '0' + min;
  }
  var sec = 60 - d.getSeconds();
  if((sec + '').length == 1){
        sec = '0' + sec;
  }
  $scope.data = hours+':'+min+':'+sec;
}, 1000);
```

and in your view just template with data like this

```
<p>{{data}}</p>
```